# FFMPEG Covert from MP4 to WEBM only working on some files.

Tags: video, ffmpeg, transcoding

I have tried the following URLs, using the streamio wrapper for FFMPEG. 
The URL's are

```
http://static.bouncingminds.com/ads/5secs/baileys_5sec.mp4 (works)
http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 (doesn't work)
```

For the latter I get the following error:

```
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

The code I use to transcode them:

```
movie.transcode("test.webm", "-vcodec libvpx -strict -2") { |p| puts p }
```

As mentioned this works perfectly for the first video. Is there any specific setting I need in order to work with all mp4 videos?

Answer (score 3):

The audio encoder (`vorbis`) bails with the following message:

```
[vorbis @ 0x7ffcc292f600] Current FFmpeg Vorbis encoder only supports 2 channels.
```

Turns out that the file has only mono.

Either specify `-ac 2` to force two channels (fake stereo) or `-map v:0` to drop the audio channel.

(Or wait for [`opus` to become available in webm](http://code.google.com/p/webm/issues/detail?id=453), or ask the ffmpeg developers to fix the encoder to support mono streams)

Comment: Hello @nmair, thank you for your answer. When I'm adding -map v:0 i get the following message: `Stream map 'v:0' matches no streams.`  do you have an idea ?